# R - loop and break after value found for each Rows

Tags: r, loops, matrix, break

I have a matrix of 0-1. 
What I would like to do is to loop into this matrix and search for the 1. 
Each time a 1 has been found, to simply *jump* or pass that row, in order to only record 1 value per row.

What I am trying to know if the first episode of the sequence is a **1**. 
I was thinking there might be a solution with

```
break
```

But I am unsure how to use it properly.

So this is my first matrix

```
SoloNight = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), .Dim = 10:11)
```

This is my empty matrix - to record the **1**.

```
matSolo = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(SoloNight), ncol = ncol(SoloNight) )
```

This is my attempt to loop

```
for(i in 1:nrow(matSolo)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(matSolo)){
    if(SoloNight[i,j] == 1) break
    {matSolo [i,j] <- 1}
  }
}
```

How can I *break* after finding the value 1 for each rows ?

Any suggestion how I could do that ?

(Expected matrix)

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [9,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
```

Comment: use `which` and take the `min` to search for the first 1 in each column

Comment: @Roland - I edited with the expected matrix

Comment: You should use integers, not numbers, like `0L`, `1L`. They take less memory and are faster to work with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be fond of `for` loops and those seem like a natural choice here. Just change your code to this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(matSolo)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(matSolo)){
    if(SoloNight[i,j] == 1) {
      matSolo [i,j] <- 1
      break
    }
  }
}
```

However, this will be quite slow for big matrices. Fortunately, it's easy to translate to Rcpp:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
'IntegerMatrix firstOne(const IntegerMatrix mat) {
  IntegerMatrix res(mat.nrow(), mat.ncol());
  for (int i=0; i<mat.nrow(); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<mat.ncol(); j++) {
      if (mat(i,j) == 1) {
        res(i,j) = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}
')

firstOne(SoloNight)
```

Comment: Are you refering to previous questions ? I do like `loop` - they help me to think (and to complicate my life too !). Thanks for the `Rcpp` - it's very nice !

Answer (score 8):

You can also try

```
library(matrixStats)    
matSolo <- 1*(rowCumsums(SoloNight)==1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You may try

```
 indx <- max.col(SoloNight, 'first')*(rowSums(SoloNight)!=0)
 matSolo[cbind(1:nrow(matSolo), indx) ] <- 1
```

#### Benchmarks

```
  set.seed(24)
  m1 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 5000*5000, replace=TRUE), ncol=5000)

  khashaa <- function(){
      matSolo <- rowCumsums(m1)
      matSolo[matSolo!=1] <- 0
       }
  khashaa2 <- function(){matSolo <- 1*(rowCumsums(m1)==1)}

  roland <- function() firstOne(m1)

  akrun <- function() {
       indx <- max.col(m1, 'first')*(rowSums(m1)!=0)
        matSolo <- m1*0
        matSolo[cbind(1:nrow(matSolo), indx) ] <- 1
       }

   system.time(akrun())
   #user  system elapsed 
   #0.349   0.044   0.395 
   system.time(roland())
   # user  system elapsed 
   # 0.144   0.021   0.166 
   system.time(khashaa())
   # user  system elapsed 
   # 0.555   0.055   0.611 
   system.time(khashaa2())
   # user  system elapsed 
   #0.265   0.054   0.319 

 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(akrun(), khashaa(),khashaa2(), roland(), unit='relative', times=20L)
 #Unit: relative
 #    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
 # akrun() 2.383404 2.453934 2.298975 2.283178 2.304992 1.993665    20   c 
 #khashaa() 3.542353 3.601232 3.420879 3.429367 3.476025 2.898632    20    d
 #khashaa2() 1.900968 2.029436 1.909676 1.923457 1.948551 1.693583    20  b  
 # roland() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20 a
```

Comment: Very very very nice @akrun !

Comment: @giacomoV  It is a row/column indexing way. or else you may need `apply` with `Position` which would still be slower.

Comment: oh I see now - very good. Let's see if someone has an alternative solution, then I'll accept your answer. Thanks !

Comment: @giacomoV On a 5000*5000 matrix, the Rcpp solution on `system.time` is `0.147`, the matrixStats one with `0.596` and the `base R` indexing with `0.348`

Comment: @akrun I've modified the matrixStats solution slightly.

Comment: @Khashaa Now, it is faster, but not as fast as Rcpp.

Comment: @akrun Performance seems to be varied depending on the structure of the input matrix. For extreme case where all 1s appear in the last column, `m1 <- cbind(matrix(0, nrow=5000, ncol=5000), 1)`, rather surprisingly the Rcpp solution is the slowest.

Comment: @Khashaa Yes, it may vary.  but I guess in general Rcpp may fare well?

Comment: @akrun For I reckon, it is almost impossible to outrun Rcpp in terms of speed:)

Comment: @Khashaa I thought that `matrixStats` functions were not as fast.  But, you proved me wrong.