# In R fastest way to find the first element of each row that satisfies a condition

Tags: r, performance

Here is a matrix where each row is the realization of an MA(1) process.

```r
V <- matrix(rnorm(1000*10, mean = -1, sd = 1),
            nrow = 1000, ncol = 10)
H <- matrix(nrow = 1000, ncol = 10)
H[,1] <- -.5
for (t in seq_len(9)) {
    H[,t+1] <- V[,t+1] + .9 * V[,t]
}
```

I would like to find the first element of each row that is larger than 0. If no elements in the row are larger than 0, then I would like to return `Inf`.

Here are three different ways I have tried.

```r
find.min <- function (x) {
    e <- which(x >= 0)
    if (length(e) > 0) {
        return(min(e))
    } else {
        return(Inf)
    }
}

find.min2 <- function (x) {
    e <- Position(function(a) (a >= 0), x)
    if (is.na(e)) {
        return(Inf)
    } else {
        return(e)
    }
}

library("purrr")
find.min3 <- function (x) {
    e <- detect_index(x, function(a) (a >= 0))
    if (e == 0) {
        return(Inf)
    } else {
        return(e)
    }
}
```

And the results of benchmarking:

```r
library("microbenchmark")
> microbenchmark(apply(H, 1, find.min),
+                apply(H, 1, find.min2),
+                apply(H, 1, find.min3))
Unit: milliseconds
                   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
  apply(H, 1, find.min)  1.361127  1.490270  1.732356  1.588842  1.668582
 apply(H, 1, find.min2)  3.587456  3.791422  4.460397  4.172458  4.265154
 apply(H, 1, find.min3) 29.167030 31.414109 34.781083 33.170437 35.959100
        max neval
   6.824049   100
  10.003467   100
 135.689261   100
```

Based on this, I have three questions:

1. Why is `find.min2` slower than `find.min`? I had thought that `Position` would be faster since it quits after finding the first `TRUE`?
2. Is there a faster way that `find.min`?
3. `find.min` was my first try, and I started benchmarking because profiling revealed that this was the bottleneck in a Monte Carlo simulation that essentially computes the mean of a column of `H` across all rows where the first positive in `H` was column 4 (say). I am a bit new to R, but I was surprised that just determining the set of rows to average over could be the bottleneck. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

Based on a comment, here's updated benchmark:

```r
library("microbenchmark")
> microbenchmark(apply(H, 1, find.min),
+                apply(H, 1, find.min2),
+                apply(H, 1, find.min3),
+                replace(y <- max.col(H > 0, ties.method = "first"), y == 1, Inf),
+                unit = "ms")
Unit: milliseconds
                                                             expr       min         lq
                                            apply(H, 1, find.min)  1.321301  1.4468300
                                           apply(H, 1, find.min2)  3.669489  3.7948605
                                           apply(H, 1, find.min3) 29.390980 31.4460145
 replace(y <- max.col(H > 0, ties.method = "first"), y == 1, Inf)  0.053014  0.0854115
        mean     median        uq       max neval
  1.71449367  1.5661085  1.630354  7.575459   100
  4.40715776  4.1524930  4.322261 10.553739   100
 34.21487510 33.5333335 37.028033 44.427120   100
  0.09416856  0.0996835  0.107846  0.213543   100
```

So the suggested approach looks much faster. But why? Is `apply` slow?

Comment: Try `replace(y <- max.col(H > 0, ties.method = "first"), y == 1, Inf)`

Comment: That works great (see updated results above). Any explanation as to why it works so much better?

Comment: It is a [vectorized](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/vectorized-operations.html) approach. Much more efficient than `apply` is as you see.

Comment: An Rcpp code would probably be faster.

Comment: Ok, this is helpful. I was completely aware of vectorization. However, my belief was that this is as long as I use `apply` I am getting a vectorized approach. I now see this is wrong. But I am no closer to understanding how to recognize vectorization. Which functions are vectorized and which aren't? How do I know when I will fall into this trap again? I should be able to find good answers to this on my own, so let's leave these as rhetorical questions unless someone wants to fill out the full answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966577/r-loop-and-break-after-value-found-for-each-rows